# $r^2.\frac{d^2 R(r)}{dr^2}+r.\frac{dR(r)}{dr}-k^2.R(r)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the equation $r^2.\frac{d^2 R(r)}{dr^2}+r.\frac{dR(r)}{dr}-k^2.R(r)=0$, $k$ is a constant? Is there any special equation that fits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sketch:** Consider the ansatz $R(r) = r^n$, then we have that
\begin{align}
\left(n(n-1)+n-k^2\right)r^n =0 \implies n^2-k^2 = 0.
\end{align}
Hence, if $n=\pm k$, then $r^n$ is a solution.

Comment: Has this type of equation, that gives this kind of result, a name?

Comment: @RebecaLieYatsuzukaSilva I think it is called Euler equations https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/eulerequations.aspx